# Is it possible to use javascript to set the return value of an html file called from a batch file?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, errorlevel

In Win7, I want to pass an arbitrary integer as the return code or Errorlevel from an HTML/Javascript file back to the batch file that started it.

Is there some way I can use javascript in the HTML program to set the return or Errorlevel code?

Edit:

WooHoo! Thanks! Yeah, my IE executes the sample HTA code.

That leaves the question of how I can manipulate the Errorlevel code from out of javascript in an hta program. The wikipedia blurb says I can control the system from an hta file, but javascript doesn't seem to have any commands to do so, even though hta allows it.

I still feel like one of those paralyzed 'locked-in' patients who have to communicate by trying to blink their eyes.

Comment: yes if you use HTA - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application

Comment: WooHoo! Yeah, my IE executes the sample HTA code.

Comment: You have reached HTA, now, the rest of the problem can be handled with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20823905/2861476)